# Databinding for textarea in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

I am using angularjs for my web app.

I have 2 textareas, a add button and a delete button.

In the first text area i have few options for the user to select. If the user selects on one of the options and clicks on the add the button, this selected item should be moved from first textarea to the second text area. And if the user selects an item from the second textarea and clicks on the delete button, then the item should be moved back to the first textarea.

How to uniquely identify and bind the items selected in the textareas?

Any help on this?

Comment: I think its not possible with textarea, because textarea is simply a multiline text box, instead try select tag with multiple attribute.

Comment: Thanks. I have some something like in the below link  http://jsfiddle.net/TXPJZ/1029/.    On click of an add button, the selected item should be moved from dropdown to the textarea

Comment: I have to write a search query based on the items selected and dropped to the textaea